# Do the rules of multiple copies of a card stack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, the Chief of the Foundry grants +1/+1 to other artifact creatures I control. If I have two copies of Chief of the Foundry in play, does that mean all other artifact creatures I control get +2/+2 and do they then grant each other +1/+1 since they are "other" artifact creatures?

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct in your interpretation. Each static ability is separately applied from each other, so they stack.

It's not directly talking about abilities stacking, but:

> **112.2c** An object may have multiple abilities. If the object is represented by a card, then aside from certain defined abilities that may be strung together on a single line (see rule 702, “Keyword Abilities”), each paragraph break in a card’s text marks a separate ability. If the object is not represented by a card, the effect that created it may have given it multiple abilities. An object may also be granted additional abilities by a spell or ability. **If an object has multiple instances of the same ability, each instance functions independently**. This may or may not produce more effects than a single instance; refer to the specific ability for more information. #